# Time derivative of curl using tensors

Tags: partial-derivative, tensors, cross-product, curl

I'm pretty new to tensor calculus; I would like to prove, as an exercise, the following vector calculus identity:

$$ \partial_t \left( \nabla \times \vec{F} \right) = \nabla \times \partial_t \vec{F} $$

using tensors and tensor notation. I've started by setting up a tensor-like expression for the $i$-th component of the curl of the general vector $\vec{F}$, thus:

$$ \left( \nabla \times \vec{F} \right)^i = \varepsilon^{ijk} \nabla_j F_k $$

Now I take the time derivative of the expression:

$$ \partial_t \left( \nabla \times \vec{F} \right)^i = \partial_t \left( \varepsilon^{ijk} \nabla_j F_k \right) $$

At this point I started having doubts about the procedure. Following my reasoning I should apply the product rule and hope that the only non-zero piece of that expression will be $\varepsilon^{ijk} \nabla_j \left( \partial_t F_k \right) = (\nabla \times \partial_t \vec{F})^i$. I'm not even sure about the $\partial_t F_k$ on the l.h.s.: should that be considered a twice covariant tensor?
Anyway applying the product rule:

$$ \partial_t \left( \varepsilon^{ijk} \nabla_j F_k \right) = \left( \partial_t \varepsilon^{ijk} \right) \nabla_j F_k + \varepsilon^{ijk} \left( \partial_t \nabla_j \right) F_k + \varepsilon^{ijk} \nabla_j \left( \partial_t F_k \right) $$

Now the term containing $\partial_t \varepsilon^{ijk}$ vanishes. It should also vanish the term with $\partial_t \nabla_j$ in it, but I'm not sure how to justify it. Therefore I would remain with:

$$ \varepsilon^{ijk} \nabla_j \left( \partial_t F_k \right) = \left( \nabla \times \partial_t \vec{F} \right) $$

Is this reasoning correct? If yes, how would you justify the fact that $\varepsilon^{ijk} \left( \partial_t \nabla_j \right) F_k$ vanish? And do I have to consider $\partial_t F_k$ as a twice covariant tensor $T_{tk}$ or should I treat $\partial_t$ like an intrinsic derivative $\delta_t$?

P.S. Thanks in advance for your answers and excuse my poor Engliush, I'm still practising it!

Comment: You can write $\left( \nabla \times \vec{F} \right)^i = \varepsilon^{ijk} \color{red}{\partial_j} F_k$. Then there are no problems with commutativity of $\partial_t$ and $\partial_j.$

Comment: I think this shall work only in Cartesian coordinates, because of the vanishing property of $\Gamma^\cdot_{j \cdot}$ right? Thus I suspect the initial identity (the one from vector calculus) can't work in the general case because of the non trivial commutativity, can it?

Comment: $\nabla_j F_k - \nabla_k F_j = \partial_j F_k - \partial_k F_j$ because the $\Gamma$-terms cancel. Check it yourself, it's easy.

Comment: understood! Thanks a lot, and have a good day sir!